# Display any content to front end

Tags: php

I am creating site in which i have given editor to user to insert anything (like text,image,video,table,.... ) and i save this entry to database.

(user can copy and paste anything  in to editor.)

When i fetch this record from database table and display to front end ,
if its only text inserted by user then its simple to apply Substr to fetch Record  and add readmore link to read full content.

but getting problem when its rather than text then how can i display content as it is what user inserted??

pls suggest me solution what i do ???

Comment: Are you sure you want to display _anything_ the user has entered? Including cross-site-scripts? Including malformed HTML?

Comment: What other content is there? Is it html markup? Have you tried strip_tags()

Comment: @JanDvorak:-No,i have skip script,sorry not explain in question.

Comment: @jtheman:-dont want to ignore tags.

Comment: Still your question is unclear to me. Could you add sample code what you have and what you want?